# MSBuild project to test a C++ program

Tags: msbuild

I have a .vcxproj file that compiles a C++ program. I would like to create a second MSBuild project file that tests the program by running it, but only if the program has been rebuilt since the last successful test. How can I access the "TargetPath" of the program from the second project file?

If I could access TargetPath as an "item" from the .vcxproj file, then the the tester project file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Build" Inputs="@(TargetPath)" Outputs="@(TargetPath->'%(filename).test-passed)'">
    <Exec Command="@(TargetPath)" />
    <Touch Files="@(TargetPath->'%(filename).test-passed)'" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I would like to execute the test using a separate project file from the compilation of the program, to make it easier to choose between build-and-test or build-and-debug within Visual Studio, without multiplying the build configurations.

Comment: Just use `Import` to import the vcxproj? Should give you access to every property and item in it. I suggest changing your target name to something else than Build though, for clarity and because it already exists in the vcxproj

Comment: I tried changing the target name and using `Import` as you suggested. This won't work with my Visual Studio use-case, since we can only build the "well-known" targets: Build, Clean, etc. Also, I couldn't figure out how to refer to the output of the imported build target. I think that my goal is possible using the MSBuild, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run a native program compiled by a separate .vcxproj using the MSBuild task. Use the `<Output>` element to create an Item with the "TargetOutputs" from the C++ application build. However, if you are building a "native" program, "TargetOutputs" is normally blank. In this case, use the "GetNativeTargetPath" target to get the output path. The following project .vcxproj file works with Visual Studio. It builds test_build.vcxproj. The test_build.exe file is run, if it has changed since the last successful run.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{80DB0D71-72E0-4FB1-B53F-EFB858A1D5A8}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>nordic_test_run</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="test_build.vcxproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="BuildExecutable">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="Build" BuildInParallel="True" />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="GetNativeTargetPath" BuildInParallel="True">
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="NativeTests" />
    </MSBuild>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="BuildExecutable" Inputs="@(NativeTests)" Outputs="@(NativeTests-&gt;'%(filename).test-passed')">
    <Exec Command="@(NativeTests)" />
    <Touch Files="@(TestTargets-&gt;'%(filename).test-passed')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```